# What are the radio band present in the hidden phone menu?

Tags: 4g

Not locked to it or anything (plenty of efs backups) just wondering what differences there are between say, the US band and the Cellular 800 band.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, you just what to know differences in bands  only?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the **range of frequencies** that each carrier use. The usage of these frequencies is regulated by the [Federal Communications Commission (FCC).](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Communications_Commission)

---

> The usage of the different frequency bands varies around the globe
>   although there is a large degree of standardisation. The GSM
>   frequencies available depend upon the regulatory requirements for the
>   particular country and the ITU (International Telecommunications
>   Union) region in which the country is located.

For instance, in North America the USA uses both **850** and **1900 MHz** bands, the actual
 band used is determined by the regulatory authorities and is dependent
upon the area.

Since spectrum is a finite resource, the FCC distributes spectrum licenses geographically into a number of areas, and mobile operators must bid on each area individually. A license owner **can use any technology within the licensed area and frequency range** subject only to the band rules defining the limits.

*Here are the  charts that includes the 3G, 4G (LTE) network technologies, bands, and frequencies of all five major U.S. carriers:*

[image]

[image]

*NB: bandwidth — refer to the range of frequencies that can be contained within a signal.*

For more information read [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_frequencies_in_the_US) and [here](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/smartphone-bands-explained/)

Acknowledgements

- [Smartphone bands explained](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/smartphone-bands-explained/2/)